# Lato font rendering on Google Chrome on Windows

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

I have tried searching for an answer for this and cannot find one. I have downloaded Lato webfont from www.latofonts.com and have the following in my css file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoLight';
    src: url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lato';
    src: url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'); 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
```

This looks great in every browser on Mac (safari, chrome, firefox) and on firefox on windows BUT it looks blurry in chrome on windows and is missing parts of letters e.g. the top of capital "T"'s . Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Try `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;`

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot or create a JSFiddle demonstration?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.  I tried all sorts of things, but in the end i found the best solution is to just add a little javascript browser detect that adds a body class.  Then override any font-weights below 400 to be 400.  For some reason the anti aliasing on windows in chrome really makes thin fonts look horrible.

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question. I added svg file and the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LatoLight';
    src: url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
         url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.svg#LatoLight') format('svg');
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'LatoLight';
        src: url('fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.svg#latolight') format('svg');
    }
}
```

in order to know what you have to put after the "#" you have to open svg file to see what the id is